# create new classic blog sites - sharepoint online using powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, blog, classic-experience

Since we can no longer create blog site on sharepoint classic.
Can we still use powershell to create a blog site - sharepoint classic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint online PowerShell:
[Documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/new-sposite?view=sharepoint-ps)

```
New-SpoSite -Title “Site Title” -Owner “owner@yourCompany.com” 
-StorageQuota 1000 
-URL https://<yourTenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/newBlogSite 
-Template BLOG#0
```

SharePoint On-Prem PowerShell:
[Documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/new-spsite?view=sharepoint-ps)

```
New-SPSite https://webApp/sites/newBlogSite 
-OwnerAlias "DOMAIN\OWNER" -Language 1033 
-Template BLOG#0
```

---

***In both instances, specifying the *Template* parameter as BLOG#0 is critical.***

Answer (score 2):

**No**. The `BLOG#0` template is removed from the server side, as per my test.

It is recommended to use the modern [communication sites](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/creating-a-blog-with-communication-sites-and-news-posts-a3db52fc-b48f-486a-be6a-336c3f9c41ce) for blogging from now on.